# How inputAccessoryView gets sized?

Tags: ios, uikit, nslayoutconstraint, inputaccessoryview

How the size of an `UIResponder.inputAccessoryView` controlled? It's too magical!

Answer (score 1):

This has been bugged me for a long time.

With my experiences and observation on iOS 12 Simulator, there're two cases,

1. Without Auto-Layout.

   UIKit adds a height constraint automatically and its
   constant value is based on frame size of the
   accessory view at loading point. It seems the
   constraints are actually translated Auto-Resizing
   constraints. You can find height-related constants
   and actually modify them, but as it is implementation
   detail, it's not recommended to do it. I strongly
   recommend to use Auto-Layout approach.
2. With Auto-Layout.

   If size is not solvable at loading point of the
   accessory view, UIKit gonna add some explicit
   width/height constraint based on its fitting size.

   If these requirements are satisfied, UIKit
   just uses existing constraints, and does not 
   change anything.

   - **`intrinsicContentSize`** must return proper values.
     If it contains `UIView.noIntrinsicMetric`, UIKit adds 
     its own height constraint.
   - Size of the view is solvable by Auto Layout system.

   As these constraints are set by yourself, it's safe 
   to modify them as you want. Also, accessory view 
   will be resized according to its content, therefore
   this is the only regular and recommended way to 
   layout accessory view with dynamic size.
3. With Auto Layout and `UIInputView.allowsSelfSizing`.

   Basically same with Auto Layout (#2), but you don't need to
   provide `intrinsicContentSize` if you set the flag to `true`.
   This is more explicit option.